# Is there a convention for deb package names?

Tags: debian-packaging

Considering how Debian-based packages have just a simple name as identifier, it seems too easy to accidentally get a naming collision, unlike with e.g. Flatpaks that use a reverse-domain style identifier.

Is there a standard or convention so one does not need to check the potentially hundreds of even remotely relevant deb repositories for a name collision just in case one very niche package actually clashes with the name?

Comment: No, there is not. And in fact, multiple name collisions and renames within the official Debian repositories have occurred in the past (`chromium-browser` vs `chromium` vs `chromium-bsu`, `gnuit` vs `git` vs `git-core`).